# Can you select a jquery mobile toggle and set cookies?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, setcookie

I Have a select tag containing options that must be used on mobile using jquery. I'm trying to use php to check when the cookie is selected in order to link to the java script and make a decision depending on the selection. This works perfectly when you the input tag on web, I cannot use the input tag on mobile therefore i've had to switch over to the select tag. If anyone has any advice. I've included a link to a snippet of what I am working with.

I can't use :checked with the select tag as far as I know so i've opted to use :selected instead?

```js
$("#flip-min").on('select', function() {
  var isChecked = $("select[id='flip-   min']:selected").length;
  var cookieName = 'TEST_TWO_MOBILE';

  if (isChecked == 1) {
    cookieName = "TEST_MOBILE";
  }
  setCookie('userChoiceMobile', cookieName);
  location.reload();
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

<div class="containing-element">
  <select name="flip-min" id="flip-min" data-role="slider" <?php echo (isset($_COOKIE[ 'userChoiceMobile']) && !empty($_COOKIE[ 'userChoiceMobile'] ) && ($_COOKIE[ 'userChoiceMobile'])=="TEST_MOBILE" ) ? "selected" : "";?>>
    <option value="off">ONE</option>
    <option value="on">TWO</option>
  </select>
```

https://codepen.io/winterlion/pen/NWPBLJN

Comment: For starters, you are subscribing to the wrong event - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/select_event: _“The select event fires when some text has been selected.”_ You want https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event

Comment: $("#flip-min").on('change', function() {